# How to resolve ORA-28000: the account is locked in oracle

Tags: oracle, installation, oracle11g

I had oracle 11g installed on my pc and for some reason, I needed to uninstall it and I did. The problem is now that I am trying to install it again, I face this issue as in the picture. [image: the issue of am facing]

if I hit ignore it will remain stuck.

Comment: For uninstallation, I followed their official guide and stopped the services, removed the path, removed the keys, removed the oracle files, etc.

Comment: Most articles on this error code are addressing issues connecting to a working database , but your issue looks like it occurs during execution of DBCA to create the database in the first place.  I googled 'dbca ora-28000 the account is locked' and got a hit that talked about your installtion OS user not being a member of the necessary OS (Linux) groups.  This looks very like yours: http://sunilthetechfreak.com/2014/09/02/ora-28000-account-locked-error-while-creating-database-using-dbca-on-grid-infrastructure-with-asm-on-standalone-server/

Comment: @Barbaros closed the question as a "duplicate", but - as far as I can tell - for a **wrong** reason. Barbaros, the database doesn't exist yet, it is just being created. Nobody can connect to it and ALTER USER to UNLOCK it. This is a completely different issue, as Ed Stevens described (and yes, I believe he knows, he is a DBA).

Comment: Thanks @Littlefoot and EdStevens, voted to reopen.